# 'Column 'RCountry' does not belong to table Table.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

The thing is in my view employee page I have a option called edit where it goes to new page to edit the details of employee here.I am using this line to get the data from sql server to text box and it's showing this error, I have cross checked the column name hell lot of times I don't know where the error is. I have been using a stored procedure to get value from the database

I have all the process for this none helped me.

```
txtrcountry.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RCountry"].ToString();
```

This is my stored procedure which is used to insert edited data to database

```
USE [PMS v1.0]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[editemp]    Script Date: 15-02-2019           09:54:19 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[editemp](@empid int )

as
begin
select Employeeid,firstname,lastname,Gender,convert(varchar(20),(convert(date,DateofBirthday,105))) as  DateofBirthday,Mobilenumber,
Alternatenumber,Emailid,AlternateEmail,Fathername,
Mothername,AadhaarCardNo,PanCardNo,PassportNo,UserName,Password,RAddressLine1,RAddressLine2,RCity,RState,RZipCode,RCountry,
PAddressLine1,PAddressLine2,PCity,PState,PZipCode,PCountry,OAddressLine1,
OAddressLine2,OCity,OState,OZipCode,OCountry from newemployee with(nolock)    where Employeeid=@empid 
select sno,Employeeid,languagename,Expertise from employeelanguges  with(nolock) where Employeeid=@empid 
end
```

This is another stored procedure which is used to get the data from database

```
USE [PMS v1.0]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[anotherpageupdateemp]    ScriptDate: 15-02-2019 09:57:36 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[anotherpageupdateemp]
(
@Employeeid int,@firstname nvarchar(20),@lastname nvarchar(40),@Gender nvarchar(10),@DateOfBirth nvarchar(20),
@Fathername nvarchar(20),@Mothername nvarchar(20),
@Emailid nvarchar(20),@AlternateEmail nvarchar(20),@AadhaarCardNo nvarchar(20),
@PanCardNo nvarchar(20),@PassportNo nvarchar(20),@UserName nvarchar(20),
@Password nvarchar(20),@Mobilenumber nvarchar(20),@Alternatenumber nvarchar(20),@RAddressLine1 nvarchar(40),
@RAddressLine2 nvarchar(40),@RCity nvarchar(30),@RState nvarchar(30),@RZipCode nvarchar(20),@RCountry nvarchar(30),
@PAddressLine1 nvarchar(30),@PAddressLine2 nvarchar(30),
@PCity nvarchar(20),@PState nvarchar(20),@PZipCode nvarchar(20),@PCountry nvarchar(30),@OAddressLine1 nvarchar(30),@OAddressLine2 nvarchar(30),@OCity nvarchar(20),
@OState nvarchar(20),@OZipCode nvarchar(20),@OCountry nvarchar(30)
)
as
begin
update newemployee set firstname=@firstname,lastname=@lastname,Gender=@Gender,DateofBirthday=@DateOfBirth,Fathername=@Fathername,Mothername=@Mothername,
Emailid=@Emailid,AlternateEmail=@AlternateEmail,AadhaarCardNo=@AadhaarCardNo,PanCardNo=@PanCardNo,PassportNo=@PassportNo,UserName=@UserName,
Password=@Password,Mobilenumber=@Mobilenumber,Alternatenumber=@Alternatenumber,RAddressLine1=@RAddressLine1,
 RAddressLine2=@RAddressLine2,RCity=@RCity,RState=@RState,RZipCode=@RZipCode,RCountry=@RCountry,PAddressLine1=@PAddressLine1,PAddressLine2=@PAddressLine2,
PCity=@PCity,PState=@PState,PZipCode=@PZipCode,PCountry=@PCountry,OAddressLine1=@OAddressLine1,OAddressLine2=@OAddressLine2,OCity=@OCity,OState=@OState,OZipCode=@OZipCode,OCountry=@OCountry

where Employeeid=@Employeeid
end
```

txtrcountry is the textbox id and RCountry is the column name I should get the details of the country in the textbox.

Comment: Where is the ","(comma) after RCountry in the stored procedure select statement.??

Comment: Yes I missed it but after putting " , " it is showing this error **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function anotherpageupdateemp has too many arguments specified.'** @Gagan Deep

Comment: Check your anotherpageupdateemp stored procedure. this should be easy to find.

Comment: @Gagan Deep I have checked it twice but there are no extra arguments can u check it once for me plz

Comment: @Gagandeep can you pls tell me where the extra arguments are passed in stored procedure I mean at which part of code

Comment: can you share your dataset dtst definition. does it have rcountry in datatable

Comment: @Gauravsa I have solved that error but now this error is coming **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function anotherpageupdateemp has too many arguments specified.'** I have checked the stored procedure I think there is not extra arguments.

Comment: can you post your c# code for where you are putting the data to database.

Comment: @DilliPrasad please post your c# code where you are adding parameters to the command object.

Comment: not sql, c# code

Comment: Sorry for asking this how can I post the code it is showing too long in the comments basically I am new to stack overflow this was my first question

Comment: post code in your question. click on edit in your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your number of parameters in C# side isn't same as the stored procedure. Your parameters should correspond like this:

- @Employeeid
- @firstname
- @lastname
- @Gender
- @DateOfBirth
- @Fathername
- @Mothername
- @Emailid
- @AlternateEmail
- @AadhaarCardNo
- @PanCardNo
- @PassportNo
- @UserName
- @Password
- @Mobilenumber
- @Alternatenumber
- @RAddressLine1
- @RAddressLine2
- @RCity
- @RState
- @RZipCode
- @RCountry
- @PAddressLine1
- @PAddressLine2
- @PCity
- @PState
- @PZipCode
- @PCountry
- @OAddressLine1
- @OAddressLine2
- @OCity
- @OState
- @OZipCode
- @OCountry

Answer (score 0):

yes I have solved the whole error Thanks @GaganDeep and @Gauravsa for helping me this error is solved

I have passed an extra argument in C# code

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", empenty.Role);
```

I removed this line which solved my Bug